# Not All Public Properties Showing In Object Initialization

Tags: c#, object, properties, initialization

When creating a DateTime object, there are only 4 properties available in the Object Initialization list, however this class has atleast 10 public properties. I was curious why wouldn't all the public properties be available in the Object Initilization as this has always been the case in the past. (Note once the object is created I could then use datetime. and see all the properties.)

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime() { 
   Date = null,
   DayOfWeek = null,
   TimeOfDay = null,
   Kind = null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show only those properties which are `Public` properties and have a `Setter`

You code won't compile because these properties don't have a `Setter` they are `Read Only`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you. However it is odd then that it shows these 4 properties as it turns out they are also read only. So why display them in the Object Initializer list if they cannot be assigned to?

Comment: +1 to OP for the weird find. Yes, they do show even though they are read-only. Very peculiar. In comparison, TimeSpan does not show any properties in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Because all those properties are readonly (only `get` accessor is provided). The code you posted will not compile.